# RabbitMQ acknowledge message outside the consumer at a later stage

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

Using RabbitMQ is it possible to directly acknowledge a message with its deliverytag ? Instead of creating a consumer or subscriber (pub/sub) to read messages and acknowledge them, my goal is to read the messages do something with them and acknowledge them at a later stage

Comment: This is not how you use ACK. It is meant to be used as it is named: as an acknowledgement of reading. So you can either ack it or not, but not "ack it later", because it belongs to the message like in a "transactional" matter. Why do you need to acknowledge it later?

Comment: I am building 2 seperate console apps 1 or many(multiple consumers) to consume from publisher and 1 to acknowledge messages. The reason why I want to consume later is because I want the consumer to re-read or get the messages again if requested to. I do not want messages to be acknowledged immediately. At the same time i do not want to send message at the back of the queue. Acknowledgement of messages will be done selectively on different console. Is this somehow possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a builtin functionnality to achieve what you are looking for, but I guess you can handle it this way:

- Create 3 rabbitmq queues: one for your "console apps", one for buffer, one for your "acknowledge apps"
- Ensure incoming messages are posted in both "console apps" and "buffer" queues using proper routing and binding keys
- Configure "buffer" queue to transfert messages to "acknowledge queue" after a delay using Rabbitmq TTL options (with a deadletter exchange)

This way, you will have:

- Incoming messages are duplicated into two queues
- console apps can consume (and acknowledge) messages right away from the first queue
- the second queue acts as a buffer and keeps message for a moment before sending them to a third queue
- Later on, messages from the third queue are "acknowledged" by your app.

Documentation reférences:

- [Routing messages](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-dotnet.html)
- [Rabbitmq TTL](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html)
- [Rabbitmq Deadletter exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html)